# ggplot won't populate with a map of the united states

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, heatmap

I am trying to make a heat map of the US, the code "works" but the data won't populate into a US map - only the names of the states show up - which I also want to populate, but the actual map of the US is most important.

Here's my code:
    #read in my data
    rawdata_path <- c("~/R/heatdata.xlsx")

```
# Import the data into RStudio:
rawdata <- readxl::read_excel(rawdata_path, sheet = 1, col_names = TRUE)

#clean up the data
rawdata$Lattitude <- as.numeric(rawdata$Lattitude)
rawdata$Longitude <- as.numeric(rawdata$Longitude)

#plot the data
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
ggplot(rawdata, aes(x=Longitude, y = Lattitude, group = rawdata$State))+
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=FinalCount))+
  geom_path()+
  geom_text(data = rawdata, aes(x=Longitude, y = Lattitude, label = State))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(heat.colors(10)), na.value = "grey90")+
  coord_map()
```

---

This is what the head of data frame called, rawdata looks like, I want the states to populate by the Count column - 1 being lightest and 10 being dark red:

```
 State        Count Group Lattitude  Longitude       Rev
 <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
arizona        1.0     1  33.50000 -112.05000       0.0
arkansas       1.0     2  36.36000  -94.20000       0.0
georgia        1.0     3  33.82000  -84.32000       0.0
hawaii         1.0     4  21.30000 -157.85000       0.0
kansas         1.0     5  38.97167  -95.23525       0.0
maryland       1.0     6  38.98000  -77.08000       0.0
missouri       1.0     7  39.09000  -94.58000       0.0
oregon         1.0     8  45.51000 -122.68000       0.0
pennsylvania   1.0     9  40.43000  -79.97000       0.0
rhode island   1.0    10  41.82000  -71.41000       0.0
tennessee      1.0    11  35.10000  -90.00000       0.0
texas          1.0    12  29.76043  -95.36980       0.0
louisiana      2.1    13  30.44000  -91.12000  209250.0
indiana        2.3    14  38.30000  -85.72000  231605.9
oklahoma       2.7    15  35.22000  -97.34000  274377.9
michigan       3.8    16  42.73000  -84.48000  381528.5
florida        4.9    17  30.43826  -84.28073  498338.5
california     5.1    18  34.06000 -118.24000  511472.0
illinois       5.3    19  41.83000  -87.68000  537913.5
kentucky       5.7    20  38.22000  -85.74000  562077.0
new york       6.3    21  40.75000  -73.99000  630642.8
massachusetts  9.5    22  42.33038  -71.16619  908952.0
north carolina 10.0   23  36.07000  -79.82000 1571923.8
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to produce a choropleth map with this data, it is pretty easy with `choroplethr`. First you need to rename your states column as "region" and count column as "value"

So input data looks like:

```
df <- structure(list(region = structure(c(1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 
15L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 11L, 8L, 18L, 14L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 
10L, 16L, 13L, 17L), .Label = c("arizona", "arkansas", "california", 
"florida", "georgia", "hawaii", "illinois", "indiana", "kansas", 
"kentucky", "louisiana", "maryland", "massachusetts", "michigan", 
"missouri", "new york", "north carolina", "oklahoma", "oregon", 
"pennsylvania", "rhode island", "tennessee", "texas"), class = "factor"), 
value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2.1, 2.3, 2.7, 
3.8, 4.9, 5.1, 5.3, 5.7, 6.3, 9.5, 10), Group = 1:23), .Names = c("region", 
"value", "Group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -23L
))
```

The script is pretty simple:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(choroplethr)

choro <- state_choropleth(df) + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Reds")
choro
```

[image]

Comment: This is wonderful and exactly what I was looking for! thank you so much! i'll definitely be utilizing more of this package.

Comment: One question - I don't understand where the "L" comes from in the structure section of the data frame. How did you get these numbers and why are they in that order?

Comment: @DanaOrinick That is the output from the `dput` function where I tried to replicate the important parts of the data you posted. The L suffix indicates an integer. For the purposes of the script, they are not really relevant. You need to just change the column names and make sure the states are lowercase. see: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/choroplethr/vignettes/b-state-choropleth.html

Answer (score 1):

The following code will load and plot a map of the United States with the coordinates and text from 'rawdata':

```
# Load the data
rawdata_path <- 'C:/data.xlsx'
rawdata <- readxl::read_excel(rawdata_path, sheet = 1, col_names = TRUE)

#clean up the data
rawdata$Lattitude <- as.numeric(rawdata$Lattitude)
rawdata$Longitude <- as.numeric(rawdata$Longitude)

library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
# Load the map of the United State
all_states <- map_data("state")

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon( data=all_states, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group), 
            colour="white", fill="blue" ) +
  geom_point(data=rawdata,
         aes(x=Longitude, y=Lattitude, colour='red', size=Count),
         alpha=I(0.5)) +
  geom_text(data = rawdata, aes(x=Longitude, y = Lattitude, label = State)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(heat.colors(10)), na.value = "grey90")
```

Running it gives this map:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! The data I am using is the data frame above. This is the spreadsheet that I am reading in called heatdata.

Comment: I duplicated your Excel file and updated the answer.